# Como mantener el valor consultado de un spinner sqlite android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

buenas quisiera saber como mantengo el valor de mi consulta sqlite en mi spinner el cual carga pero no mantiene el de la consulta y muestra el primer item

La consulta si se realiza llena el spinner
llena con todos los valores y muestra el primer item y necesito  que se llene con el valor de la consulta su valor asignado

El este es del oncreate

```
 consultarListaTipoCancha();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                custom_spinner,
                listaTipoCancha
        );
        adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown);
        comboTipoCancha.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Este para consultar el valor asignado

```
private tipo_cancha verTipoCancha(int id) {
    Cursor cursor;
    tipoCanchaList =new ArrayList<tipo_cancha>();
   tipo_cancha tipoCancha=null;

    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  tipo_cancha.nombre from cancha, tipo_cancha, num_cancha, sede " +
            "where cancha.id_tipocancha=tipo_cancha.id_tipocancha and  cancha.id_numerocancha=num_cancha.id_num_cancha and cancha.id_sede=sede.id_sede and cancha.id_cancha=" + id + " LIMIT 1", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        tipoCancha=new tipo_cancha();
        tipoCancha.setNombre(cursor.getString(0));
        tipoCanchaList.add(tipoCancha);

    }
    obtenerLista();
    cursor.close();

    return tipoCancha;

}
```

este para llenar todos los valores del spinner

```
private void consultarListaTipoCancha() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();

    tipo_cancha t=null;
    tipoCanchaList =new ArrayList<tipo_cancha>();
    //select * from usuarios
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ Utilidades.TABLA_TIPO_CANCHA,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        t=new tipo_cancha();
        t.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        t.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));


        tipoCanchaList.add(t);

    }
    obtenerLista();

}
private void obtenerLista() {
    listaTipoCancha=new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<tipoCanchaList.size();i++){
        listaTipoCancha.add(tipoCanchaList.get(i).getNombre());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso del listener `OnItemSelectedListener`, para que al seleccionar el elemento puedas obtener la posición del elemento seleccionado.

por lo tanto realiza lo siguiente:

```
private int elementoSeleccionado = 0;

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 //define variable para elemento seleccionado.
                 elementoSeleccionado  = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
               
            }
        });
```

Para mantener el valor consultado, usa el método `setSelection(indice)` definiendo el índice del elemento el cual se seleccionará automáticamente, recuerda que inicia desde 0.

```
spinner.setSelection(elementoSeleccionado);
```